# ocamlbuild specify output location/name

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

Can I specify the build location and file name with the ocamlbuild tool? I would like to be able to say (in pseudocode):

```
ocamlbuild myapp.ml -b native -o bin/myapp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option, but `ocamlbuild` is extensible and allows you to add your own options with `Options.add`. Of course, you will also need to add some implementation. Basically, hijacking the rule for `native` and extending it with installation procedure may work. To extend `ocamlbuild` you should [write](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/ocamlbuild/Making_plugins.html) a plugin (other option is to create your own standalone executable, and use it instead of ocamlbuild, that is what we're doing in our [project](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/bapbuild.ml)).

But for most purposes it is enough to use standard tools like `ocamlfind`, `oasis`. I would suggest to look at the latter, as it is more high-level.

### Oasis

With `oasis` you need to write a simple `_oasis` file (or use `oasis quickstart` to write it interactively). The minimum file would look something like this:

```
OASISFormat: 0.4
Name:        myapp
Version:     0.0.1
Synopsis:    My first application in oasis
Authors:     Authors list
Maintainers: Maintainer Name 
License:     MIT
Copyrights:  (C) Copyright Holder
Plugins:     META (0.4), DevFiles (0.4)
BuildTools: ocamlbuild

Executable "myapp"
  Path:           .
  MainIs:         myapp.ml
  Install:        true
  CompiledObject: best
```

After the file is finished, run

```
oasis setup
```

that will generate `Makefile` and `configure` script. Run

```
./configure
```

as usual to check and setup your environment. E.g., `./configure --prefix=$HOME` will setup your build system to install into your home folder (i.e., to executables to `~/bin`, etc). I usually prefer to install onto opam stack, and use `./configure --prefix=$(opam config var env)`

And finally, usual pair of

```
make && make install
```

Will do the work.

### OCamlfind

`ocamlfind` will still require your to write META file. Usually they write them by just copy-pasting and editing the META file from some existing project. But it is not hard to write one, as it is very well [documented](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/findlib.html).

After the meta is written, you can use `ocamlfind install` subcommand which has a `-destdir` option.

But `ocamlfind` doesn't handle executables, only libraries. So this may not suit you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you provide the equivalent statement in oasis and/or ocamlfind?

Answer (score 1):

With entering `ocamlbuild --help`, I cannot find a such option.

One solution is to write a script doing this :

```
#!/bin/bash 

ocalmbuild myapp.native // build your executable
mv myapp.native bin/myapp // rename it
```

**EDIT:**

Following suggestion of ivg, you should replace the line `mv myapp.native` bin/myapp by `cp -L myapp.native bin/myapp`.

Maybe someone can give this option, which I found interesting but in the user manual, there is not. So one solution is to use script.

Comment: I would suggest to use `cp -L` instead of `mv`. First of all `mayapp.native` is a link to a real file, second, it is used to control the state of ocamlbuild cache and it is better not to remove this link, unless you're really know what you're doing.