# Change the name of the produced executable with Oasis

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, oasis

Well, title says it all, I want to change the name of my executable because right now I have

```
Executable myexec
  Path:                 .
  BuildTools:           ocamlbuild
  MainIs:               main.ml
  CompiledObject:       best
```

And it produces a file `main.native` instead of `myexec`, for example.

What I tried to do is to write

```
PostBuildCommand: cp -L main.native myexec
```

But that's because I know it will produce a file `main.native`. What if on another computer it produces a `main.byte` executable. I can't write :

```
PostBuildCommand: cp -L main.* cubicle
```

I find it awful. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619162/ocamlbuild-specify-output-location-name) but, strangely, the Oasis part answers to the location question but not the executable name.

Answer (score 0):

When you will do `make install` or, alternatively, `ocaml setup.ml -install` it will install `main.native` as `myexec`. If you really don't want to install into the system, then you can try to configure with prefix equal to `$(pwd)` and still install, in that case it will install it in your project folder, under a correct name, e.g.,

```
ocaml setup.ml -configure --prefix `pwd`
make
make reinstall
```

Comment: I don't want to install. I guess the best way to do it is to rename my `main.ml` file in `myexec.ml` and I'll get a `myexec.native|byte`.